# What's the relation between molecular orbitals and electron density?

Tags: wavefunction, electrons, physical-chemistry, orbitals

The way [molecular orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital) are drawn represent the "encapsulated" space in which the wave function has a significant amplitude. How do I obtain from this the [electron density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_density)? Is there a fundamental difference been them? And why "everyone" talks about orbitals if the electron density is what actually we're interested in?

Answer (score 2):

The electron density is proportional to the square of the wavefunction. More precisely it's:

$$ D \propto \Psi\Psi^* $$

where $\Psi^*$ is the complex conjugate of the wavefunction. The wavefunction can be complex, but the product $\Psi\Psi^*$ is always real, which is just as well since the electrons are real too.

So a diagram of the electron density looks very like a diagram of the wavefunction, which is why people tend not to make the distinction clear.